# Make homepage a non-Wordpress page

Tags: urls, homepage

I have a website (`www.example.com`) that I'd like to add a WordPress blog to, but I want to keep the website's `index.php` as the homepage.

I also want to add two links to the homepage, `example.com/newsletters` and `example.com/explainers`, which link to WordPress archive pages with all the posts tagged "newsletters"and "explainers" respectively.

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Put the regular site in the root folder and install WordPress in a subfolder, such as www.example.com/blog.

Comment: That's my current solution, but can it allow for the URL structur `example.com/newsletters`? Wouldn't it have to be `example.com/blog/newsletters`?

Answer (score 0):

Put the regular site in the root, install WordPress in a subfolder and use server URL rewriting pointing to WP for specific URLs.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are the easiest way to include a wp-blog in an existing website. URL-issues as you mention in your comment should be solved by the current website's software, or you can put a redirect in you `.htaccess`.

However, depending on how your current website is structured, you can also turn it around: build a WP site and incorporate your current site in it. Using a conditional `is_home`, for instance, you could redirect WP to the `index.php` page of your site to retrieve the homepage.

As said, much depends on the structure of your current site, and where you want to take it in the future. That makes your question actually a bit too broad for a Q&A model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The `is_home` option sounds appealing, given the non-WP part of my site is very simple (one PHP page). Would you mind elaborating on it?